# Android TableRow selected value

Tags: android, tablerow

How to get first column value in android TableRow and pass the value to next activity?
For e.g on my android activity, I have a TableRow with each row having 3 columns (nodeID, Value, Date)
if TableRow view has 4 rows and user selects/clicks any row, how can I get value of nodeID for the selected row?

```
---------------------------
nodeID| Value | Date      |
---------------------------
1     | Test  | 2-Feb-2016|
---------------------------
2     | ABCD  | 2-Feb-2016|
---------------------------
3     | WXYZ  | 2-Feb-2016|
---------------------------
4     | Tes1  | 2-Feb-2016|
---------------------------
```

if user selects row WXYZ than value 3 should be pass to next activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
below code should help in Main activity
tableRow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                    TableRow tablerow = (TableRow) view;
                    TextView sample = (TextView) tablerow.getChildAt(0);
                    String result=sample.getText().toString();
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("nodeID",result);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

=======================================================

onCreate(){
String data= getIntent().getStringExtra("nodeID");

}
```